# How to create Multiple Zuul Filters in one Gateway App

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

How to create multiple (pre/post) filters in zuul gateway app (spring boot).

Example:

```
/endpoint1 - should call (Filter 1)
/endpoint2 - should be served by (Filter2)
```

Currently I understand that every request comes to gateway, will be handled by one Filter (pre, route,post)

Comment: Can you please tell what are you trying to achieve? There might be a simpler solution than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple filters for one endpoints or many endpoints.

If you want to apply filter for some endpoints and not for others, you can use the `shouldFilter()` method of this filter (e.g pre filter) to define the use case. Something like :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    String endpointToFilter = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getRequestURI();
    endpointToFilter = endpointToFilter.substring(0, endpointToFilter.indexOf("/", 1));
    boolean shouldFilter = "endpoint1".equals(endpointToFilter);
    return shouldFilter;
}
```

Comment: Does it mean I can only have one Filter class and I will have to check conditions in shouldFilter? if you see this project [https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sample-zuul-filters], there are many filters written in Same application. How it is decided that when which filter is called?

Comment: You can have all the filters you want.

By default, all filters are called but the shouldFilter() method define if the filter will be applicated.

Important : the order of filters is defined by the filterOrder() method.